# How to avoid floating of next section to the next page?

Tags: moderncv

Please help!!! I can not stop latex to push my next section into the new page.

I'm writing my CV in moderncv latex. My \section{Education} is in the first page, but when I insert the code for next section, which is \section{Research Experience}, it unnecessarily goes starts from next page. I know that this section is big and it all doesn't fit in the first page, but how can I start it from the point the first section ends.

### here are my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\firstname{Sam} 
\familyname{Ryan}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{Program in ...}{Adam street, ...}
\mobile{xxxx}
\email{xxx}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
%---------------------------------------------------------------------
\section{Education}
\cventry{2012--2014}{M.Sc. in}{}{}{}{}
\cvlistitem{\textit{\textbf{Thesis:}} }
\cventry{2006--2011}{B.Sc. in }{}{}{}{}
\cvlistitem{\textit{\textbf{Thesis:}}}
%-------------------------------------------------
\section{Research Experience}
\subsection{\textbf{Dr. XXX, Chemistry department}}
\cventry{2016-present}{Research Associate in Vaccine Lab}{}{I work on ...}{}{\textbf{Projects}:
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Extraction and purification ....
        \item Synthesis and characterization of .... :
        \begin{itemize}
            \item{Synthesis of .....}
            \item{Synthesis of .....}
            \item{Fabrication of ....}
            \item{Encapsulation of ....}
            \item{Recombinant ....}
        \end{itemize}
        \item Evaluation of ...
        \item Combinatorial ...
        \item Coating of ...
        \item In-situ formation ...
    \end{enumerate}}
%-------------------------------------------------
\section{Interests}
\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~} % Changes the symbol used for lists
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete minimal example. Use filler text to avoid including personal details. Right now, that won't push anything to page 2 if only because it won't ever start typesetting page 1.

Comment: Please post a full, but minimal example. Code snippets are usually worthless for TeX-related problems. A proper example begins with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and only includes enough content to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: To format code, highlight it and press the `{}` button or ctrl+k.

Comment: This doesn't reproduce the problem. It produces only 1 page: nothing is pushed to the second page.

Comment: Good point, because I just put ... in each line, but in actually each of those ... are 4 lines. So, if you put three or four lines in each line instead of ...., then the whole section will go to the next page.